# Using a string of quoted values in a variable for a SQL WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, where-clause, quotes

The answer escapes me...maybe because it is not possible...

Example that works...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE FIELD1 IN ('aaa','bbb','ccc')
```

Example that does not work...

Attempt to leverage variable so that I can define the values once in a string of statements

```
DECLARE @ListValues VARCHAR(50)

SET @ListValues = '''aaa'',''bbb'',''ccc'''

SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE FIELD1 IN (@ListValues)
```

This is is obviously only a small part of the equation and for other reasons...

I cannot leverage a table for the values and change this to a true sub-query

The closest question I could find was this one... but does not cover my requirements obviously...
[Storing single quotes in varchar variable SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745645/storing-single-quotes-in-varchar-variable-sql-server-2008)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the reformat marc_s, i saw the result of post and was in the process of doing the same...checking out answers...

Comment: Asked [so many times here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause).  I think conceptually I'd prefer the table-value-function version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `IN` operator expects a **list** of items - here strings.

What you're supplying with your `@ListValues` variable however is a **single** string - not a list of strings.

What you could do is use a table variable and store your values in it:

```
DECLARE @ListOfValues TABLE (ItemName VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @ListOfValues(ItemName) 
VALUES('aaa'), ('bbb'), ('ccc')

SELECT *    
FROM TABLEA 
WHERE FIELD1 IN (SELECT ItemName FROM @ListOfValues)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @ListValues VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ListValues = '''aaa'',''bbb'',''ccc'''
      ,@SQL = 'SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE FIELD1 IN ('+@ListValues+')'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your whole SQL query dynamically (say it's stored in a string variable `@sql`),
and then execute it with `EXEC (@sql)`. Better yet, use the `sp_executesql` SP
because this approach is more secure (less prone to SQL injection) than `EXEC`.

See: [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` operator in SQLServer expect a list of values, your variable is a single string, the query parsed will be different

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE FIELD1 IN ('aaa','bbb','ccc')
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE FIELD1 IN ("'aaa','bbb','ccc'")
```

**Attention:** the double quotes are there only for readability, to get the string with single quote in it.

if you know a programming language the first one is like searching in an array, the second is a string.

To store a list in your variable it need to a table

```
DECLARE @varTable TABLE (field1 varchar())
```

So that you can use it in your `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE FIELD1 IN (SELECT field1 FROM @varTable)
```

To add values to the table variable use an `INSERT` statament like usual for tables.